# Response for curl is empty beeing called from gradle on CircleCI

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have a task in gradle which downloads translations for android APP

```
task('downloadTranslations') {
    ext.downloadPOTranslation = { stringsFile, projectId, lang ->
    def f = new File(stringsFile)
    if (f.exists()) {
        println("Delete file: " + f.absolutePath)
        f.delete()
    }

    println("Get lang: " + lang + " for project: " + projectId)

    def requestArray = ['curl', '-X', 'POST', "\"https://api.poeditor.com/v2/projects/export\"",
                   '-d', 'api_token=\"{API_KEY}\"',
                   '-d', 'id=\"' + projectId + '\"',
                   '-d', 'language=\"' + lang + '\"',
                   '-d', 'type=\"android_strings\"']

    println(requestArray)
    def request = requestArray.execute()

    request.waitFor()
    def response = request.text
    if (response.isEmpty()) {
        def errorResponse = request.err.text
        println("Error response from server:")
        println(errorResponse)
    } else {
        println("Response from server:")
        println(response)
    }

    ...

}

doLast {
    downloadPOTranslation("src/main/res/values/strings.xml", "projectNumber", "en-gb")
}
```

}

When I call this task from local machine from CLI or Android Studio everything works fine:

```
Get lang: en-gb for project: 250751
[curl, -X, POST, "https://api.poeditor.com/v2/projects/export", -d, api_token="API_TOKEN", -d, id="250751", -d, language="en-gb", -d, type="android_strings"]
Response from server:
{"response":{"status":"success","code":"200","message":"OK"},"result":{"url":"https:\/\/api.poeditor.com\/v2\/download\/file\/FILENUMBER"}}
```

But when I try exact the same on CircleCI I got an error:

```
Get lang: en-gb for project: 250751
[curl, -X, POST, "https://api.poeditor.com/v2/projects/export", -d, api_token="API_TOKEN", -d, id="250751", -d, language="en-gb", -d, type="android_strings"]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/circleci/code/app/build.gradle' line: 204

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:downloadTranslations'.
> java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Stream closed happens because `response.isEmpty()` is `true` and `request.err` is closed.

So **why it could be so that Gradle fetch an empty response from server while same works locally?**

I've also tried SSH to CircleCI and run curl directly from CLI - response is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in difference betwee `'` and `"`.

I don't know why but probably `'curl'` was some kind of ignored.

So

```
    def requestArray = ["curl",
                        "-X", "POST",
                        "-d","api_token=API_KEY",
                        "-d", "id=" + projectId + "",
                        "-d", "language=" + lang + "",
                        "-d", "type=android_strings",
                        "https://api.poeditor.com/v2/projects/export",]
```

Works fine.